# How to determine a trendline given a set of values, which represent changes of a particular metric over time?

Tags: statistics, time-series, regression-analysis

I would like to calculate a trendline. I have these metrics - minimum, maximum, average, median, mode, range, each point comes with a time that measurement was taken. Is that data sufficient for calculating a trend or do I need some other metrics? 
My initial though is to apply some modification of 'the longest sequence of consecutive natural successors' to find the start and the end point of the trend. 
That piece of data comes from a financial domain. 
My math background is not a strong one, so if you can point me to some articles to read on this topic - I'll be grateful. 
Here's my data sample (17 points, average metric used, date is represented as a number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970):

```
 data:[71.911509,71.928993,71.907168,71.947290,71.915951,71.925802,71.930942,71.894793,71.796717,71.723729,71.675488,71.693242,71.690964,71.687208,71.692363,71.683531,71.642414], 

 timestamps:[1449158406112,1449159306393,1449160207362,1449161108128,1449162006643,1449162905018,1449163805674,1449164704940,1449165604534,1449166504159,1449167404237,1449168304924,1449169204815,1449170104565,1449171003940,1449171903956,1449172804378]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is somewhat vague, but then I suspect you are just
getting started with your project. Without knowing more specifics
of your data it is hard to say exactly where you should start.
Here are some very generic suggestions; I hope some of them are
useful in helping you think through this project.

Begin by picking your favorite 'metric' to use for a predicted variable, and plot it against time. If the plot looks roughly linear, use simple linear regression to see if you can find a regression line through the data that satisfies your definition of 'trendline'. If you have no obvious favorite, start with means or
medians.

It is possible that many of the metrics you mention will behave
similarly. If your purpose is to predict what comes next, pick
the metric you'd most want to predict. Your ability to predict far into
the future will likely be very limited, especially if there are
changes in the
underlying economic, social, and other underlying conditions
for which you do not have data.

If the data suggest that a simple curve fits better than a line, try using
various transformations of your metric (predicted variable).
If metrics take only positive values, perhaps logs or square roots.

Another choice would be to try to fit a quadratic or cubic curve.
You'd do that by having 'predictor' variables $t$ and $t^2$ (for
quadratic, add $t^3$ for cubic).

If you notice cycles (periodic up and down trends) in your
metric when plotted against time, then you need to explore
some of the methods of time-series analysis.

**Addendum,** I looked some plots of your data. There seems to be
a 'change point' about halfway along. There are tests for this,
but time series is no an area in which I feel comfortable giving
detailed advice. I'm wondering if all your data sequences show
this kind of behavior, or whether you showed this particular
one because of its unusual structure. Also, I wonder if detecting
the location of a change point (beyond what is obvious from the
plots) is useful for you.

[image]

A 'control chart' of individual data points shows that the process
changes from 'out of control' above the 'upper control limit' (UCL), which is 2SD above the mean, to out of control below the LCL.
(Characteristically for control charts, SD is estimated using the range of the data). Red dots indicate out of control and `1`s indicate the
reason (out of a standard numbered list) for so tagging the value.

[image]

A 'runs' chart (not posted) shows a notable sequence of runs 'above
the median' followed by a similar sequence 'below'.

There is nothing profound in either chart
beyond what is clear from the initial unembellished 'time series' plot of 'data'
against (essentially equally spaced) 'timestamps'. I would start
by Googling some of the key terms and looking in an introductory
applied book on time series. Posting this problem on our sister
site 'stats;crosvalidated' might get you advice for a time series
expert.

Comment: ok, will do that. I'm getting started on exploring the data I gathered over some period of time. I can provide samples of the data, if that will help

Comment: Happy to take a preliminary look at a small sample, if you can append it to your Question. Preferred format is a sequence of values of a metric, separated by commas. Then a sequence of times (of equal length, of course), also separated by commas.

Comment: Is there any way for me to be in touch with you ? My e-mail address is in my profile. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I assume you are addressing Bruce?

Comment: @BruceET I added some sample data, let me know if I can expand and/or reformat it

Comment: actually, I had trouble choosing applied book on time series - most of them are heavy on the math side and not so much about practice